# How to redirect URL into a new URL using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect pages using .htaccess. I am using code igntiter
When user type this URL in addresss bar :

```
form.bixy.com/salesapp
```

and they hit enter button, the URL should changed into:

```
form.bixy.com/salesapp/administrator/addusr
```

I have this .htaccess inside the `salesapp` folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|system/application/sources/) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/  

</IfModule>
```

If the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/` is removed, I got `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

I have little knowledge about .htaccess. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is my current .htaccess that I put **inside** salesapp folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|system/application/sources/)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php  [L]

RewriteRule ^/? /salesapp/administrator/addusr[NC,R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

It still give me error, but the URL should've worked

`The page isn’t redirecting properly`

`Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `salesapp` you can try this .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /salesapp/

RewriteRule ^(?:administrator)?/?$ administrator/addusr [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|system/application/sources/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php  [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's working great. But, one litlle thing, How to make it so when the user type `form.bixy.com/salesapp/administrator/` it also redirected to `form.bixy.com/salesapp/administrator/addusr`

Comment: it is not working when I type `form.bixy.com/salesapp`. It should work for both `form.bixy.com/salesapp` and `form.bixy.com/salesapp/administrator` which wil be redirected to `form.bixy.com/salesapp/administrator/addusr`

Comment: Ah I had a typo. Try it now, missed a `?` after non-capture group